# Want to copy screenesaver file in System32 folder instead of SysWow64 on 64bit Machine

Tags: .net, windows, 32bit-64bit, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am creating Setup and deployment project in which i have one screensaver file and Framework 4.0 file. I am installing this setup using Setup created by project. The system in which i am installing this package is 64bit system. Now i want to install my screensaver in System32 Folder but it goes to SysWow64 though i have selected Default Location "C:\Windows\System32".
Please provide suggestion for this problem ASAP.

Comment: Is your screen saver compiled as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Comment: CodyGray its is compiled as 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I asked in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456866/want-to-copy-screenesaver-file-in-system32-folder-instead-of-syswow64-on-64bit-m#comment23607972_16456866) is an important one:

> Is your screen saver compiled as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

The deal is that 32-bit applications go into the SysWow64 folder, and 64-bit applications go into the System32 folder. Simple enough, right?

I know that seems backwards—the one that contains *32*-bit applications has *64* in the name—but it was done for backwards-compatibility reasons. Lots of people hardcode paths, like System32, into their applications and installers. Let this be a lesson to you: committing these sins leads to inescapable ugliness in the future.

So if your screen saver is compiled as a 32-bit application, it belongs in the SysWow64 folder, not in the System32 folder. The system is smart enough to know this, so it's automatically doing the right thing and redirecting your application into the appropriate folder. On a 32-bit Windows installation, your 32-bit screen saver will indeed be placed into the System32 folder.

I suppose you could override this behavior, but I'm not going to tell you how. If you really want your screen saver to be in the System32 folder on 64-bit Windows, you should re-compile it as a 64-bit app.

Comment: if i forcefully required this screensaver file in System32 folder on 64-bit System then what should i do?

Comment: Why would you want that? It would be a lie. That folder contains 64-bit files, and you are not one.

Comment: i want to push screensaver file to all my networks machine  from server and for that i need to have it in common folder(i.e. system32 folder) for 32bit/64 bit machines

Comment: The operating system knows what folder it should be in. You can deploy everywhere to System32, and WOW64 redirection will take over to make sure it's in the right place for 64-bit Windows.

Comment: that's fine i will look forward to another best way for it. thanks for response.